# Springmail send email for invalid address

Tags: spring

When Spring sends an email, there is no status return. In general, we use a simple try catch to determine the local email sent to the mail server.
Problem: In the javax mail jar, there is a provided email address to get invalid email SendFailedException exception caught
Spring, I did not find the corresponding method

Because the company’s sales staff are changing frequently, the effective email address today may be deleted by the administration tomorrow.
Having an invalid email address will result in the entire email not being sent out. I need to get its address, remove it from my address array and resend it.

Ps: Restrictions: 1.spring mail send 2. send together, do not send one copy
The big guy is free to give his opinion, thank you very much for your thanks.
Of course welcome irrigation

Answer (score 0):

Asked himself, there is no corresponding method to deal with springmail, my program will log the debug information into the log file, through the io operation log file to obtain the corresponding invalid address address, it is recommended to use javax.mail jar
getInvalidAddresses() method with SendFailedException exception,Thanks